# Select Number of Rows Inside Another Query of the Same Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select the number of rows from a select query inside another query. Here's what I have:

```
SELECT `userId`, `groupId` AS gId, (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
        SELECT * FROM `groupcommits` WHERE `groupId`=`groupcommits`.gId
    ) temp_table
) AS `numberOfCommitedUsers` FROM `groupcommits` 
LEFT JOIN `groups` ON `groups`.`id`=`groupcommits`.`groupId`
LEFT JOIN `institutions` ON `institutions`.`id`=`groups`.`institutionId`
WHERE `groupcommits`.`userId`=userId;
```

This doesn't work right now, it causes a 1064 error. I want, for each row, `numberOfCommitedUsers` to contain the number of rows in `groupcommits` with that row's `groupId`. How can I do this?

Thank you,

--

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT g2.`userId`, g2.`groupId` AS gId, (
       SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM `groupcommits` AS g1
       WHERE g1.`groupId`= g2.`groupId`) AS `numberOfCommitedUsers` 
FROM `groupcommits` AS g2
LEFT JOIN `groups` ON `groups`.`id`= g2.`groupId`
LEFT JOIN `institutions` ON `institutions`.`id`=`groups`.`institutionId`
WHERE g2.`userId`= userId;
```

The extra nesting level you used in the subquery is redundant.

Comment: Thank you for the response! When I run this, I get this error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'groupcommits.gId' in 'where clause'`. Why is this? Do you know what would cause this?

Comment: @UnknownUser Using tables aliases simplifies things a bit I think. Please check the edit I made.